# What exactly is meant by convex surfaces?

Tags: convex-analysis, vector-analysis, surfaces, spherical-coordinates, solid-angle

Google search didn't show up. It just shows up information related to spherical mirrors everywhere.

**Is there a way to intuitively (and maybe formally) define convex (and concave) surfaces around a point $P$?**

The following is an extract from my book:

"Now, the surface $S$ being convex, the quantity $\cos (\hat{r},\hat{n})$ is positive for every element $d\omega$ and can not become null in any of them."

Here the author is referring to the solid angle formula at point $P$ due to a surface $S$:

$$dS=\dfrac{r^2}{\cos (\hat{r},\hat{n})}\ d\omega$$

where the symbols have their their usual meanings.